# Support for wildcards with Workload Identity Federation

Tags: google-cloud-iam, workload-identity

I am currently testing this [Github Action](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth/) to authenticate with gcloud resources using Workload Identity Federation.

I created a Workload Identity Provider with a custom `repository_ref` attribute mapping both the Github repository and branch from which the Github Action was used:

```
gcloud iam workload-identity-pools providers create-oidc "my-provider" \
  --project="${PROJECT_ID}" \
  --location="global" \
  --workload-identity-pool="my-pool" \
  --display-name="Demo provider" \
  --attribute-mapping="google.subject=assertion.sub,attribute.repository_owner=assertion.repository_owner,attribute.repository_ref=assertion.repository:assertion.ref" \
  --attribute-condition="attribute.repository_owner=username" \
  --issuer-uri="https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
```

When granting service account impersonation rights I can then use this command to ensure that The Github Action is triggered from the `my_repo` repository's `master` branch:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding "my-service-account@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
  --role="roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser" \
  --member="principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/${WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_POOL_ID}/attribute.repository_ref/username/my_repo:refs/heads/master"
```

While that works great to match an exact branch name, I would also like to use the same to grant authentication on all tags creations using a wildcard:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding "my-service-account@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
  --role="roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser" \
  --member="principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/${WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_POOL_ID}/attribute.repository_ref/username/my_repo:refs/tags/*"
```

It does not seem to work at the moment. Are there plans to support this? And is there an alternative I could use at the moment?

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve this question?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK wildcards are not supported.

Try this instead:

```
--member="principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/${WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_POOL_ID}/attribute.repository/username/my_repo"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mapping using the regex `match` function (using it as a "flag" attribute), and then allow access when the flag attribute is "true".

In my case, for example, I added the following mapping: `attribute.is_version_tag_push`=`assertion.ref.matches(R"^refs/tags/v(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)$") ? "true" : "false"`

Note: I created it using the GCP Console, so you probably need to escape the quote characters if using the gcloud command.

(i.e. the field will be "true" when I push a tag with the `v*.*.*` pattern, and "false" otherwise)

And then I set the following `principalSet` to the service account:
`principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/<POOL_ID>/attribute.is_version_tag_push/true`.

---

Also, particularly for you case, if you want to allow access for **any** tag push, you can simply make use of the `ref_type` Github field (can be `branch` or `tag`, depending on what was pushed)

Some resources that might be of help:

- [Google Workload mapping capabilities](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation?_ga=2.200938029.-263526674.1694534268&_gac=1.251641204.1698589430.Cj0KCQjwhfipBhCqARIsAH9msbltzKg5p7bzLUy-4yJmV8St7hxY4hMbM62b1P6lZc2fJZjfhdghwS4aAs40EALw_wcB#mapping)
- [CEL expressions docs](https://github.com/google/cel-spec/blob/master/doc/intro.md#introduction) (used in the fields mappings)
- [re2 Syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) (regex syntax used by CEL)
- [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) (choose Golang to test the re2 syntax of your expression)
- [Github available token attributes](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/about-security-hardening-with-openid-connect)
- [Github attributes - 2](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts)